# How to pass values from Ajax to another function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a help to understand how to export values from ajax fucntion and import that into a different function 
example

```
 function getlanlon(){
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/getlatlng",
                  //data: {value: 0},
                  //async: true,
                  success: function(result){

                   console.log(result)
                  }

              }, "json");
          };
```

Now, We need to call this "result" into bellow function but does not work, the console.log always show undefined.

```
          map.on('load', function () {

             latlon= getlanlon()
               console.log(latlon)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a callback or promise or deferred object:

```js
function getlanlon(callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/getlatlng",
        //data: {value: 0},
        //async: true,
        success: function(result){
            if(callback){
                callback(result);
            }
            console.log(result)
        }

    }, "json");
};

map.on('load', function () {

    getlanlon(function(latlon){
        console.log(latlon)    
    })
}
```

Or using Deferred object.

```js
function getlanlon(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/getlatlng",
        //data: {value: 0},
        //async: true,
        success: function(result){
            deferred.resolve(result);
            console.log(result)
        }

    }, "json");
    
    return deferred;
};

map.on('load', function () {
    
    getlanlon()
        .then(function(latlon){
            console.log(latlon);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `latlon = getlanlon`? What would `latlon` contain?

Comment: No use of it, copy paste issue. I edited the answer.